# Textbox shows Previous typed text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[Ajax Auto Complete Extender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zjQG.png)
Issue:i want to Search Some Data.
If i am trying to type shown previous types text . I want to remove previously typed text.The system stored previous typed text.

Answer (score 1):

AjaxAutoCompleteExtender property

```
EnableCaching
```

is true by default. try changing that setting to false. that should fix your issue.